# Pandas: create new column in one dataframe with values based on matching key from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes, the first dataframe has two columns assumed to be the key and value and the second dataframe contains only the keys and I want to add a new column in the second dataframe the values for this column should be the values for the matching keys from the first dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vi' : ['a','b','c','d','e'],'s':[2,5,7,0,1]})  
tf = pd.DataFrame({'vi' : ['b','d','c','a','e']})    
df    

vi  s  
 a  2  
 b  5  
 c  7  
 d  0  
 e  1  

tf  

vi    
 b  
 d  
 c  
 a  
 e  

result tf  

vi  s  
 b  5  
 d  0  
 c  7  
 a  2  
 e  1
```

Answer (score 5):

When merging, you want to specify `left` to ensure that all the values from `tf` are contained in the new dataframe.  As both dataframes have the same name for the key column, specify `on='vi'`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vi': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'z'],
                   's': [2, 5, 7, 0, 1, 10]})  
tf = pd.DataFrame({'vi': ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'f']})

>>> tf.merge(df, how='left', on='vi')
  vi   s
0  b   5
1  d   0
2  c   7
3  a   2
4  e   1
5  f NaN
```

I've extened both datasets by one non-unique value.  Note how the result above differs from a simple merge, which does an inner join by default.

```
>>> tf.merge(df)
  vi  s
0  b  5
1  d  0
2  c  7
3  a  2
4  e  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) `tf` with `df` using `tf.merge(df)`, example with results below:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'vi' : ['a','b','c','d','e'],'s':[2,5,7,0,1]})  

In [3]: tf = pd.DataFrame({'vi' : ['b','d','c','a','e']}) 

In [4]: tf = tf.merge(df)

In [5]: tf
Out[5]: 
  vi  s
0  b  5
1  d  0
2  c  7
3  a  2
4  e  1
```

Which is the result you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

When columns are appended to a dataframe, the row index is determined by the index.

You can set the index using

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'s':[2,5,7,0,1]})  
df.index = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

By default the index is a range of integers from 0 to N-1.